# JPanel transition, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am new to java, and learning new things everyday.
Today i stumbled upon an error i just can not get fixed.
So i've got a JFrame with a JPanel inside, now I want to remove the Jpanel when i click on my Start game JLabel, and make it transition into my game JPanel ( for now i use a test JPanel)

JFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainMenu extends JFrame {

JPanel panel;
JFrame frame;
JButton playlabel;

 public void mainmenu()   {

    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    playlabel = new JButton ("Nieuw Spel");

//frame
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(14,36,69));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getMinimumSize());  
    frame.setVisible(true);

//panel        
    Dimension expectedDimension = new Dimension(690, 540);
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.setPreferredSize(expectedDimension);
    panel.setMaximumSize(expectedDimension);
    panel.setMinimumSize(expectedDimension);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(14, 36, 69)); 
    panel.add(playlabel);
    playlabel.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

//playlabel        
    playlabel.setFont(new Font("Old English Text MT", Font.BOLD, 40));
    playlabel.setBounds(250, 350, 50, 20);
    playlabel.setForeground(new Color(217,144,39));
    playlabel.setBackground(new Color(14,36,69));
    playlabel.setBorderPainted(false);
    playlabel.setFocusPainted(false);
    playlabel.addActionListener(new PlayListener());
}
private class PlayListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel panelgame = Game.Game();
            this.remove(panel);
            this.add(panelgame);
            this.revalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Game class:

```
package labyrinthproject.View;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game {
public static JPanel Game(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(690, 540);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255,36,69));
    return panel;
   }
}
```

if anyone could explain this to me why this doesn't work, it would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Sincerely,
A beginner java student.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some issues in your code

- Create the GUI on the event dispatch thread
- Don't extend JFrame (you have three (three!) JFrames floating around there!)
- Follow the naming conventions
- Don't overuse static methods
- Only store the instance variables that you *really* need to represent your class state
- Don't use manual `setSize` or `setBounds` calls. Use a LayoutManager instead
- The call to `frame.setVisible(true)` should be the *last* call, after the frame has been completely assembled
- Consider a CardLayout for switching between panels ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html )

Slightly cleaned up, but the exact structure depends on what you actually want to achieve at the end:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainMenu extends JPanel
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mainMenu);

        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    MainMenu()
    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Dimension expectedDimension = new Dimension(690, 540);
        setPreferredSize(expectedDimension);
        setBackground(new Color(14, 36, 69));

        JButton newGameButton = new JButton ("Nieuw Spel");
        newGameButton.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        newGameButton.setFont(new Font("Old English Text MT", Font.BOLD, 40));
        newGameButton.setForeground(new Color(217,144,39));
        newGameButton.setBackground(new Color(14,36,69));
        newGameButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        newGameButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        newGameButton.addActionListener(new PlayListener());
        add(newGameButton);
    }

    private class PlayListener implements ActionListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            removeAll();
            GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
            add(gamePanel);
            revalidate();
        }
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    GamePanel()
    {
        setBackground(new Color(255,36,69));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know that my code is all still messy and ugly, but i'm trying to get better at it! so tnx for your help, i will definitely check out the cardlayout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `JButton` and not a `JLabel`. Then:

you add to your JButton : `Your_JB.addActionListener(this);` (don't forget to implement `ActionListener` to your class).

Now, we are gonna add the detector:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src = e.getSource();
                if(src == Your_JB){
                    panel.setVisible(false);
                }
    }
```

When you click the button, it will make your panel disapear.

Comment: I figured that i used a very misleading button name: i named my Jbutton, playlabel. playlabel = new JButton ("Nieuw Spel"); I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.remove(panel);
this.validate();
this.repaint();  //if you use paintComponent 
this.add(panelgame);
this.revalidate();
```

Swing is hard to making nice UI. You just need to use `validate()` after `remove()`.

I hope it's helpfull.